# Supabase query to get all songs from the artists a user follows

Tags: sql, postgresql, supabase

I'm rather to new to Supabase and i'm trying to find a way to structure and to retrieve all the songs from the artists that a user follows.

With the code below i can retrieve all artists a user follows. I do this by storing userids in an array (param1 = userid)

```
create or replace function getArtists(param1 text) returns setof artists as $$
select *
from "artists"
where param1 =ANY(artistFollowers);
$$ language sql;
```

I can't however find a way to retrieve all songs from the artists that a user follows.

```
create or replace function getAllSongs(param1 text) returns setof songs as $$
select *
from "artists"
where param1 =ANY(artistFollowers)
inner join songs on artist.artistid == songs.artistid
$$ language sql;
```

Simplified table structure.

```
artists TABLE
  _id SERIAL,
  artistname character(40),
  artistFollowers ARRAY[userid1, userid2, userid3]
  artistid character(40)

songs TABLE
  _id SERIAL,
  songname character(40),
  artistid character(40)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using arrays to store related table's id, in a relational databases we use a join table to do so. You can read more about it [here](https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/18/fmp/en/index.html#page/FMP_Help/many-to-many-relationships.html), but you could create a table something like this, where the table is referencing both the artists table and the users table. You didn't have the definisions of your users table, but I assume you do have a public users table here.

```sql
create table public.artist_followers(
  artist_id int references(public.artists.id) not null,
  user_id uuid references(public.users.id)
);
```

Whenever a user follows a new artist, you insert a new row in this table with the artist_id and the user_id.

Now, when you want to retrieve the list of songs created by the artists that a user follows, you could use an database function liks this to query it.

```sql
create or replace function getAllSongs() returns setof songs as $$
select *
from songs
where artist_id in (select id from artists inner join artist_followers on artists.id = artist_followers.artist_id where artist_followers.user_id = auth.uid());
$$ language sql;
```

Comment: Thank you. I updated my question with the table for artists and songs. To clarify. I am currently (subscribing to artists) by storing userids in the artistsFollowers field. This was a user can retrieve all artist where his userid exists within the array. This works well, However i am also trying to see how i can retrieve all songs from the artists that a user is subscribed to.

Comment: @Redstain Ah, I see. I have updated my answer for how you can model your data in SQL databases.